# ANTLR4 parse tree viewer in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, antlr, antlr4

Trying to view specific portions of the parse tree inside of methods generated by ANTLR4 inside Eclipse Kepler Release.  For instance ANTLR generates an 'enter/exit' method for a grammar rule created called FunctionDefinition.

Inside the FunctionDefinition method I'm able to getText from the child nodes inside context.  Is there a way to graphically represent this context and it's child nodes, via a plugin etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FunctionDefinitionContext` object returned from the parser extends [`RuleContext`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/RuleContext.html), so you can call [`inspect()`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/RuleContext.html#inspect%28java.util.List%29) on the object to view the result graphically.

```
FunctionDefinitionContext ctx = parser.functionDefinition();
Future<JDialog> futureDialog = ctx.inspect(Arrays.asList(parser.getRuleNames()));
// wait for the dialog to close (if you want)
Utils.waitForClose(futureDialog.get());
```